# Protractor ConfigParser Error 105 getPage Timeout when trying to print to console

Tags: javascript, protractor

In Protractor, I need to run one line of code from the test suite called mytest:

```
console.log('my first Protractor test');
```

I am not loading any webpages. I am only printing to the console.

I have the following latest stable versions:

- node -v => v8.11.2
- npm -v => 6.0.1
- protractor --version => 5.3.2

`C:\test\> protractor conf.js --suite=mytest`

I am getting the following error:

```
[15:59:08] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[15:59:08] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[15:59:08] E/configParser - C:\test\conf.js:59
    getPageTimeout: 100000, //Timed out waiting for page to load, and alternatively browser.get(address, timeout_in_millis)
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:135:26)
```

Comment: Pls share your conf.js file where this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be syntax issue before the highlighted error line(getPageTimeout) in the conf file.

In general ,Run suite as below(without '='):

```
protractor conf.js --suite mytest
```